# Blazor StateHasChanged() Never Updates My Component

Tags: c#, .net, modal-dialog, blazor

Having issues in re-rendering my component. Can anybody shed a light on where i maybe going wrong

I have a parent component and a child component, when i click a button my child component is loaded, but after i make my change and it updates the database, my component does not refresh..

I have tried all of these, with no luck.

```
await Task.Run(StateHasChanged);
await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
```

My child component is in a tab within a modal

```
<div class="tab-2">
                        <label for="tab2-2">Roles</label>
                        <input id="tab2-2" name="tabs-two" type="radio">
                        <PluginRoleManagement PluginGrid="@PluginAssocRoles" PluginMasterId="@ApplicationMasterId"></PluginRoleManagement>
                    </div>
```

And my child component

```
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids
@using Siemens.RolesAndPluginManagement.Common.Model.PluginRegisterRole
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Navigations
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Navigations.Internal
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
<div>
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <i style="color: #0cc; font-size: 50px; text-align: center" class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />
    @if (PluginGrid != null)
    {
        <SfGrid DataSource="@PluginGrid" AllowPaging="true" Height="315">
            <GridEditSettings AllowAdding="true" AllowEditing="true" AllowDeleting="true" Mode="EditMode.Normal"></GridEditSettings>
            <GridEvents OnActionBegin="EditDetails" TValue="PluginRegisterRoles"></GridEvents>

            @foreach (var app in PluginGrid)
            {
                <GridColumns>
                    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(app.Id) IsPrimaryKey="true" HeaderText="Id" Width="110"> </GridColumn>
                    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(app.Description) AllowEditing="true" HeaderText="RoleName" Width="110"> </GridColumn>
                    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(app.AdministrativeRole) AllowEditing="true" HeaderText="Administrative Role" Width="110"> </GridColumn>
                </GridColumns>
            }

        </SfGrid>
        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-info" style="background-color: #0cc; font-family: Siemens Sans Black" @onclick="AddAdminRole">Add Admin Role</button>
        <button class="btn btn-info" style="background-color: #0cc; font-family: Siemens Sans Black" @onclick="AddUserRole">Add User Role</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" style="font-family: Siemens Sans Black" @onclick="DeleteUserRole">Delete Role</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" style="font-family: Siemens Sans Black" data-dismiss="modal" @onclick="@Close">Close</button>
    }
    <style>
        .e-toolbar .e-tbar-btn {
            background: #0cc;
            color: white;
        }

            .e-toolbar .e-tbar-btn .e-tbar-btn-text {
                font-size: 1rem;
                font-family: Siemens Sans Black;
            }

        .e-grid .e-icons {
            color: #0cc;
        }

        .e-checkbox-wrapper label, .e-css.e-checkbox-wrapper label {
            bottom: 90%;
        }
    </style>
</div>

@code {
    
    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<PluginRegisterRoles> PluginGrid { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public int PluginMasterId { get; set; }
    public bool AdminRole { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public async Task EditDetails(ActionEventArgs<PluginRegisterRoles> args)
    {
        if (args.RequestType == Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.Action.Save)
        {
            PluginRoles = args.Data;
            PluginRoles.ApplicationMasterId = PluginMasterId;
            await EditPluginRoleRecord(PluginRoles);

        }

    }

    public async Task AddAdminRole()
    {
        AdminRole = true;
        Description = "You added a default admin role";
        await AddDefaultRole(PluginMasterId, AdminRole, Description);
        await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());

    }
    public async Task AddUserRole()
    {
        AdminRole = false;
        Description = "You added a default user role";
        await AddDefaultRole(PluginMasterId, AdminRole, Description);
    }
```

Maybe i am understanding how it works, but it definately does no reload the modal with the updated data, until i close the modal and re-open.

Comment: After you send the change to the backend... are you ever updating your `PluginGrid` IEnumerable? The grid is showing all the items in the `PluginGrid` variable, so while you might be sending the updates to the backend, if you aren't updating `PluginGrid` to reflect the new/edited information, then the frontend Blazor component won't ever know it's supposed to update. Are you updating the `PluginGrid` variable anywhere?

Comment: You don't have any event callback to the parent, Remember the parameters are going from the parent to the child component and update events going from the child component to the parent by using EventCallback , something like this '[Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int> YearChanged { get; set; }'
then you could call it as you want like this await YearChanged.InvokeAsync(yourvalue); 
Check this for more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: by using EventCallBack you don't need to call StateHasChanged because it will be called within the eventCallBack check the previous link for more info !

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your ideas, in the end it was myself not re-updating my List... doh.. I thought once the page refreshes it runs all the components code again. I guess it was a misunderstanding from my point. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Jeremy was correct